# Orthogonal polynomials derive normalization factor

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

I have the following problem, and have literally no idea where to start! Even a hint to get me going would be apreciated. I believe the question is concerning Laguerre polynomials.

> Let $\alpha$ > -1. Suppose that a monic orthogonal polynomial sequence
>   $\{P_n\}_{n\geq0}$ (for $\mathscr{L}$) satisfies the orthogonality
>   relation
>
> $\mathscr{L}[x^m P_n(x)] = \frac{1}{{\Gamma(\alpha +1)}}\int_0^\infty P_n(x)x^me^{-x}x^\alpha dx = N_n\delta_{n,m},$ for $m\leq n$, and $m,n
> \geq 0$
>
> with $N_n =\mathscr{L}[x^n P_n(x)] \neq 0$, for $n\geq 0$
>
> Obtain an explicit expression for $N_n$.

Comment: I tried integration by parts but got stuck. Is this the way to go or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\int_0^\infty x^{p-1}e^{-x} dx = \Gamma(p),$$
where $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).